# Running FLOWR on an xml variable as opposed to a xml document

Tags: xquery

I can successfully run an xquery FLOWR on an xml doc:

```
for $result in doc(results.xml)////sparql/results/result/binding

where $result/@name="xyz"
return $result
```

What if i want to run the same FLOWR on a variable instead?

```
for $result in $results//sparql/results/result/binding

where $result/@name="xyz"
return $result
```

this does not work. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: what is `$results` variable in the 2nd code i.e how did you declare & populate it?

Comment: $results contains an xml object returned by a sparql query

Comment: @har07 xdmp:type($results) gives untypedAtomic

Answer (score 1):

If `$results` is a document node then your syntax is correct.

If `$results` is a URI containing the location of a document that needs to be parsed, then you want `doc($results)//.....`.